# Hemispherectomy and brain changes

Tags: neuroscience

As far as i know [hemispherectomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemispherectomy) is a rare procedure when individual will going to have half brain removed in very young age. Because brain has quite remarkeble neuroplasticity patient usually will survived only with half of brain.

---

**My questions is?**

How much brain can be removed to not to negatively influence brain activity?
Does anatomy hemispherectomy alter secretion of glands for example pineal gland?

Comment: The glands are not a part of cerebral hemispheres; so they would not be removed. The wiki link also says that surgeons prefer to leave the sensorimotor cortex intact.

Comment: I didn't think functional hemispherectomy but anatomical one. I am sorry that I forget to mention that